ARC1252 cannot load key but other reader can
Have 2 different readers MicroEM and ACR1252U and 2 different cards.

Card Mifare 4k
Bank card with Mifare

1. MicroEM work correct with self driver (not PcSc)
1.1. Get UID 
1.2. Load key FFFEFDFCFBFA
1.3. Auth Sector 33 
1.4. Read block 5 / 12
All success

In docs see some difference in implement command and fix it.
But when I try ACR1252 with PCSC.
## Try Bank Card
requestUid = {FF, CA, 00, 00, 00};
return correct UID = 8073EB8A8B7B00

requestLoadKey =  {FF, 82, 00, 00, 06, FF, FE, FD, FC, FB, FA}
return 63 00

# Try simple card
requestUid = {FF, CA, 00, 00, 00};
return correct UID = 8073EF1A457B00

requestLoadKey =  {FF, 82, 00, 00, 06, FF, FE, FD, FC, FB, FA}
return 90 00

Don't understand where to look to make ACR1252 work correctly with bank card like MicroEM
Now I try to send command throw session with C2 command.
UPD 16.08.2024:
Found some Sdk with .exe applications CLICK
Used CLInfo.exe
Bank card with mifare no event.
Mifare 4k return TYPE=54 (Don't know what is that)

Then used PCSCQuery.exe
Bank card 
ATR = 3B 86 80 01 4B 4F 4E 41 13 21 3E 
Mifare 4k 
ATR = 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 36 00 00 00 00 5D

Then used APDUTest.exe
Bank card
SEND: FFCA000000
RECEIVED: UID (90 00) result success
SEND: FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF
RECEIVED: (63 00) result error
Mifare 4k
SEND: FFCA000000
RECEIVED: UID (90 00) result success
SEND: FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF
RECEIVED: (90 00) result success

After that, used other reader.
Bank Card 
UID, ATQ = 0044, **SAK = 38**
Mifare Card 
UID, ATQ = 0044, **SAK = 08**

Now I see 2 different tags (SAK)
Here I found that SAK = 38 is emulator.
And in NXP Community found post on 2017 that some readers expect 18 or 28, not 38.
To check info I readed SECTOR 0 BLOCK 0
Bank Card : UID 38 4400 810000002321 (SAK, ATQ, Manufacture)
Mifare 4k : UID 08 4400 010111002118

All in all. Question - can be answer that reader ACR1252U just does not support SAK = 38 tags.
If I found some info how to changed SAK or make ACR read Emu-Tags will update question.

It is very unlikely that a bank card is a Mifare card type.
The are usually NFC Type 4A which uses a whole different command set to Mifare Cards.
With the ACR1252 you are getting (63 00) result error as 63 indicates accord to iso 7816-4 response codes an "Execution Error" with 00 saying "no more information".
Basically it is saying you sent a wrong command to the bank card as it does not understand Mifare specific commands because it is not a Mifare Card.

We try diffrents cardreader some of them work success with card.
We think that it's unsupported cardtype for this reader. He doesn't want send ISO14443 command to that type of TAG. TAG 38 is Bank Card with Mifare specific emulation so it's supported ISO14443.
All in all we used other reader now, and our driver programmer looking for something in ACR Reader software.

So, after all, we recived answer from developers.
Answer is send
Request 00 31 36 B0 E0 00 00 23 01 C7
Where 00 32 36 B0 (SOME [D] Value)
And E0 00 00 23 01 C7 - PICC Settings command

We don't recived some answers what is [D] but send this command after startup application make ACR work with that type of card... WTF
May be that help some one)
UPD:
[D] is control key to find it you can used
ACS Smart Card and Reader Tool
With some PcSc lib it's send as pointer
var _controlCode = (IntPtr)0x003136B0;
var _sendBuffer = new byte[] { 0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x23, 0x01, 0xC7 };
byte[] _receiveBuffer = new byte[10];
var error = SCardReader.Control(_controlCode, _sendBuffer, ref _receiveBuffer);
                

But before set C7 is settings where we need 6-bit set to 1 ( NXP MIFARE ISO/IEC 14443
PICC Selection )

“NXP MIFARE ISO/IEC 14443 PICC Selection” is enabled, SAK 28h is
recognized as Mifare Classic 1K and SAK 38h as Mifare Classic 4K

But pay attention to frimware verison with command.
[D] E0 00 00 18 00
Response = E1 00 00 00 0F 41 43 52 31 32 35 32 55 5F 56 31 30 30 2E 31
Firmware Version (HEX) = 41 43 52 31 32 35 32 55 5F 56 31 30 30 2E 31
Firmware Version (ASCII) = “ACR1252U_V100.1”


Note: The setting will be saved into non-volatile memory. Bit 6 Option
is applicable only to firmware  version 111.1 and above.

